# Responsive div width with it filling the whole horizontal space left

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a navbar with the logo on the left side corner and some pages with both the logo and the page links being in different divs. I want the div named navbar to be become responsive when resizing the window, I only want the width to change.

My code:

```
<div class="top">
      <div class="logo">
      <a href="localhost:8080"><img class = "logo" src="@\assets\logo.svg" alt="site logo"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar">
        <a href="">HOME</a>
        <a href="">ABOUT</a>
        <a href="">CONTACTS</a>
```

My current css:

```
.logo{
  margin-top: 2px;
  height: 81px;
  max-width: 408px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.logo a img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.top div{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar{
  background-color: #3A383B;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color:#C29947;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.navbar a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #C29947;
  margin-right: 25px;
  font: 26;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I want the navbar div to fill the whole horizontal space next to the logo.

Comment: I guess the flexbox perfect fits what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can solve this problem.

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="localhost:8080"><img class = "logo" src="@\assets\logo.svg" alt="site logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">...</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.top {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.navbar {
    flex: 1;
}
```

for `.top`, when we declare `display: flex`, this means that container `.top` will be treated as a flexbox container, whose will render by default any children containers into a row.

`.navbar` only need a single instruction, `flex: 1`, this tell to browser : Use all available space in this row left by `.logo`

Simple and powerful!

This is a good documentation about flexbox:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/